# How to automatically move mail from POP account to IMAP account using mutt

Tags: email, imap, pop3, mutt

I have two mailboxes, one that is accessible exclusively via POP3 (user@pop.com) & a second one that supports IMAP (user@imap.com). The SMTP server that belongs to the IMAP account can send mail using both senders.

I configured `mutt` to access these accounts as follows:

```sh
#  if no folder (i.e account) selected: unset parameters
account-hook . 'unset preconnect pop_user pop_pass imap_user imap_pass imap_authenticators'


###################
# (1) POP3 server #
###################

# set login credentials for inbound mail (POP3)
account-hook 'pops://pop.server.com' " \
    set pop_user=user_pop@pop.com \
    pop_pass=secret_pop "

# define mailbox path on POP3 server
set folder=pops://pop.server.com
    mailboxes =INBOX

# set login credentials for outbound mail (SMTP) & matching from address
folder-hook 'pops://pop.server.com' " \
    set folder=pops://pop.server.com/ \
    smtp_url=smtp://user_imap@imap.com@smtp.server.com:587/ \
    smtp_pass=secret_imap \
    from='mschilli <user_pop@pop.com> ' "


###################
# (2) IMAP server #
###################

# set login credentials for inbound mail (IMAP)   
account-hook 'imaps://imap.server.com' " \
    set imap_user=user_imap@imap.com \
    imap_pass=secret_imap "

# define mailbox path on IMAP server
set folder=imaps://imap.server.com
    mailboxes =INBOX

# set login credentials for outbound mail (SMTP) & matching from address
folder-hook 'imaps://imap.server.com' " \
    set folder=imaps://imap.server.com/ \
    smtp_url=smtp://user_imap@imap.com@smtp.server.com:587/ \
    smtp_pass=secret_imap \
    from='mschilli <user_imap@imap.com> ' "
```

This way I can read mail from both accounts & send mail using the corresponding mail address.

However, I would like to have all my mail on the IMAP server to organize them in one central web-accessible space.

Unfortunately, pop.server.com does not support automatic forwarding/bouncing of user@pop.com mails to user@imap.com (I know that this would be possible by using for example mail.zoho.com).

Also, imap.server.com does not support catching user@pop.com mail from pop.server.com (I know that for example mail.google.com would support this).

What I *can* do, however, is to open `mutt` change into my pop.server.com folder using `c`, tag all messages using `T.*`, selecting them for moving using `;s` and then choosing my imap.server.com folder. This way, `mutt` fetches all user@pop.com mail from pop.server.com, uploads them to imap.server.com and deletes them from pop.server.com.

- **How can I setup `mutt` to automatically do this when I change to my imap.server.com folder?**
- **How can I setup `mutt` to set the *from* adress according to the *to* address when replying/forwarding and use 'user@imap.com' otherwise?**

Please note that I do not want to run some kind of mail server using `fetchmail` or something alike in a `cron` job. It is totally fine when the latest user@pop.com mails are missing on imap.server.com.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but `chron` in the last line should be `cron`. I would highly recommend `cron`, by the way. I mean, other than `cron` (or similarly, `launchd`, if you're on OS X), what else can you use? Write a damon yourself?

Comment: @ksh: Thx for pointing out that typo, I fixed it. Regarding what else I could use: I was hoping to configure some kind of account-hook in my `.muttrc`, so that when I open my IMAP account, `mutt` first connexts to the POP account, movies all mail and only then opens the IMAP account. However, I have no clue how to setup such an advanced `.muttrc`...